# PySide DLLs missing after pip install

Tags: python, pyqt, pip, anaconda, pyside

Win 7, x64, Python 2.7, Anaconda, Spyder 3, Qt 5

I have installed PySide using `pip` at the Anaconda command line. Then I tried to use it in Spyder 3 using the following code...

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

reply = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, "Ouija Central","Enter your thoughts for the day:")
if reply[1]:
    # user clicked OK
    replyText = reply[0]
else:
    # user clicked Cancel
    replyText = reply[0] # which will be "" if they clicked Cancel
```

..but I get the "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." error.

[image]

Anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: What is the output of `conda list pyside`? And what happens if you try to run the script without Spider (i.e. start it as `python yourscript.py`? Also I recommend to install pyside using `conda install pyside`. Any reason why you installed it with Pip?

Comment: @titusjan `conda list pyside` gives _i# packages in environment at C:\Users\nr16508\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2: # PySide 1.2.4 <pip>_. When I run the script without Spyder I get the same error. There was no reason why I used `pip` just thought that was the best way to install things. Will try & install using `conda install`

Comment: @titusjan OK uninstalled then re-installed using `conda install pyside` but still getting the same error

Comment: If you start the script as `python -v yourscript` Python will print the DLLs it tries to open. Perhaps this will give some more information. Check if it exists.